# How to hide previous element in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```html
    <div onclick="showHide(this)" class="iptv"><div class="triangle"></div><b>LUZ HD</b> - 98 kanałów (w tym 32 kanały HD)
            <div class="iptv_price"><b><img src="img/rj45.png" class="icon_oferta"/> 51,00 zł <img src="img/radio.png" class="icon_oferta"/>71,00 zł</b></div></div>
            <div style="display:none;" class="iptv_net">
                <span>IPTV + 60&nbsp;&nbsp; Mbit/s <br/> <b><img src="img/rj45.png" class="icon_oferta"/> 60,00 zł</b></span>
                <span>IPTV + 100 Mbit/s <br/> <b><img src="img/rj45.png" class="icon_oferta"/> 65,00 zł</b></span>
                <span>IPTV + 200 Mbit/s <br/> <b><img src="img/rj45.png" class="icon_oferta"/> 105,00 zł</b></span>
                <iframe src="https://www.avios.pl/pakiety/luzhd_S.html" width="100%;" height="300">Twoja przeglądarka nie obsługuje iframe.</iframe>
                <div><a href="/iptv.php?load=luzhd_S">Zobacz na pełnym ekranie</a></div>
            </div>
        
            <div onclick="showHide(this)" class="iptv"><div class="triangle"></div><b>KOMFORT HD</b> - 125 kanałów (w tym 53 kanały HD)
            <div class="iptv_price"><b><img src="img/rj45.png" class="icon_oferta"/> 61,00 zł <img src="img/radio.png" class="icon_oferta"/>81,00 zł</b></div></div>
            <div style="display:none;" class="iptv_net">
                <span>IPTV + 60&nbsp;&nbsp; Mbit/s <br/> <b><img src="img/rj45.png" class="icon_oferta"/> 70,00 zł</b></span>
                <span>IPTV + 100 Mbit/s <br/> <b><img src="img/rj45.png" class="icon_oferta"/> 75,00 zł</b></span>
                <span>IPTV + 200 Mbit/s <br/> <b><img src="img/rj45.png" class="icon_oferta"/> 115,00 zł</b></span>
                <iframe src="https://www.avios.pl/pakiety/komforthd.html" width="100%;" height="300">Twoja przeglądarka nie obsługuje iframe.</iframe>
                <div><a href="/iptv.php?load=komforthd">Zobacz na pełnym ekranie</a></div>
            </div>
            
            <div onclick="showHide(this)" class="iptv"><div class="triangle"></div><b>KOMFORT+ HD</b> - 152 kanały (w tym 69 kanałów HD)
            <div class="iptv_price"><b><img src="img/rj45.png" class="icon_oferta"/> 71,00 zł <img src="img/radio.png" class="icon_oferta"/>91,00 zł</b></div></div>
            <div style="display:none;" class="iptv_net">
                <span>IPTV + 60&nbsp;&nbsp; Mbit/s <br/> <b><img src="img/rj45.png" class="icon_oferta"/> 85,00 zł</b></span>
                <span>IPTV + 100 Mbit/s <br/> <b><img src="img/rj45.png" class="icon_oferta"/> 90,00 zł</b></span>
                <span>IPTV + 200 Mbit/s <br/> <b><img src="img/rj45.png" class="icon_oferta"/> 130,00 zł</b></span>
                <iframe src="https://www.avios.pl/pakiety/komfort+hd.html" width="100%;" height="300">Twoja przeglądarka nie obsługuje iframe.</iframe>
                <div><a href="/iptv.php?load=komfort+hd">Zobacz na pełnym ekranie</a></div>
            </div>
```

I want to write function in Javascript which show element that user click. This function is correct, but I want to also after click element n hide previous element. I don't have idea how do it. I hope someone show me some tips.

```js
function showHide(obj)
    {
        var nextObj = obj.nextSibling;
        while(!nextObj.tagName) nextObj = nextObj.nextSibling;
        nextObj.style.display = nextObj.style.display != 'block' ? 'block' : 'none';
        
    }
```

Comment: which element do you want to hide?

Comment: I have 5 div and for example I click first div(before click all div was hide, after click is show). When I click anather div(for istance 4) first div should be hide

Answer (score 0):

### Maybe use childNodes

I am not sure what do you mean by "previous element".

but I see you try to get the sibling and maybe you actually want the child of the main div.

if so.. you should use `obj.childNodes` and then you get an array:

[div.triangle, b, text, div.iptv_price]

and then you can do this:

```
obj.childNodes[1].style.display = obj.childNodes[1].style.display === 'inline' ? 'none' : 'inline';
```

so `LUZ HD` will toggle with the other elements

```js
function showHide(obj)
    {
        var nextObj = obj.nextSibling;
        while(!nextObj.tagName) nextObj = nextObj.nextSibling;
        nextObj.style.display = nextObj.style.display != 'block' ? 'block' : 'none';
      
      obj.childNodes[1].style.display = obj.childNodes[1].style.display === 'inline' ? 'none' : 'inline';
        
    }
```

```html
<div onclick="showHide(this)" class="iptv"><div class="triangle"></div><b>LUZ HD</b> - 98 kanałów (w tym 32 kanały HD)
            <div class="iptv_price"><b><img src="img/rj45.png" class="icon_oferta"/> 51,00 zł <img src="img/radio.png" class="icon_oferta"/>71,00 zł</b></div></div>
            <div style="display:none;" class="iptv_net">
                <span>IPTV + 60&nbsp;&nbsp; Mbit/s <br/> <b><img src="img/rj45.png" class="icon_oferta"/> 60,00 zł</b></span>
                <span>IPTV + 100 Mbit/s <br/> <b><img src="img/rj45.png" class="icon_oferta"/> 65,00 zł</b></span>
                <span>IPTV + 200 Mbit/s <br/> <b><img src="img/rj45.png" class="icon_oferta"/> 105,00 zł</b></span>
                <iframe src="https://www.avios.pl/pakiety/luzhd_S.html" width="100%;" height="300">Twoja przeglądarka nie obsługuje iframe.</iframe>
                <div><a href="/iptv.php?load=luzhd_S">Zobacz na pełnym ekranie</a></div>
            </div>
```

Comment: No, I added 3 div more. I want to that only one div was show, not more. So if I click second div and later I click 3 third div, so second div have to automatically hide.